# Publish jekyll website to github pages

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, github-pages

I built my own website with jekyll and uploaded it to git but I have a problem.
I followed this guide on youtube on how to upload the website: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqFjuX4VZmU&list=PLLAZ4kZ9dFpOPV5C5Ay0pHaa0RJFhcmcB&index=19

Here is the link to the actual website: https://linus345.github.io/portfolio/

and here is the link to the github repository:
https://github.com/Linus345/portfolio

The website is on the branch gh-pages and the error as you hopefully can see is:

> Error 404 page not found

What can I do to solve this problem? Comment if you need any more information.

Edit: 
I suspect that there may be some problems with the permalinks/links and thus it won't work but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try making the index page work first.
*usually* you want an html file rather than a markdown file.

Try comparing to the offical docs.
https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

The command used in the YouTube video is:

```
git push origin gh-pages
```

That would create a [`gh-pages` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/), but even your master branch shoul dbe enough here. (Since Aughist 2016, and the new "[Simplified Publication](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing)")

However, your assets URL are generated in absolute path (`/assets/img/Blogit_Logo%20kopia.png`)

That translates to the 404:

https://linus345.github.io/assets/img/Blogit_Logo%20kopia.png

instead of

https://linus345.github.io/portfolio/assets/img/Blogit_Logo%20kopia.png

See "[Customizing CSS and HTML in your Jekyll theme](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/)" and the [example repo minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [`jgd`](https://github.com/yegor256/jekyll-github-deploy) command line to simplify the deployment process. All you need to do is to install it first and then say:

```
$ jgd
```

The site will be packaged and then deployed to the `gh-pages` branch of your repo. More about it in this blog post of mine: [Deploy Jekyll to GitHub Pages](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/24/jekyll-github-deploy.html)